# Line graph data HighChart JS cannot shown

Tags: javascript, php, sql, highcharts

i wannna make a line graph  using highchart JS with data from my SQL, but unfortunately the graph just shown like this :

[image]

the graph just shown a Xline and Yline but not a data
and this is my sql code

```
$sqlX=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT DAY(tgl_daftar) as value FROM pasien WHERE MONTH(tgl_daftar) = '06' AND YEAR(tgl_daftar)='2016'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

and this my php and JS code :

```
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/exporting.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var chart1 ;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'grafik',
            type: 'column'
         },   
        title: {
            text: 'Data Pendaftaran Pasien Baru Per Bulan',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [<?php while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sqlX)){ echo "'".$r['value']."',";} ?>]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Jumlah'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: <?php echo "'".$namabulan."'" ; ?>
            <?php 
            while($date=mysql_fetch_array($sqlX)){ 
                            $date=$date['value'];                     
                                $sql_jumlah   = "SELECT tgl_daftar, COUNT(*) as jumlah_pasien 
                                                FROM pasien 
                                                WHERE 
                                                DAY(tgl_daftar) = '$date' 
                                                AND MONTH(tgl_daftar)='$bulan' AND YEAR(tgl_daftar) = '$namatahun'";        
                                    $query_jumlah = mysql_query( $sql_jumlah ) or die(mysql_error());
                                        while( $data = mysql_fetch_array( $query_jumlah ) ){
                                            $jumlah = $data['jumlah_pasien'];  }             
                                    ?>

              data: [<?php echo $jumlah ; ?>]

            <?php   
                } ?>
        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

thanks, Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Could you show an example of what the value of $jumlah would be in your data array, as well as what the x-axis categories ($r['value']) would be?

Comment: How your data does it look like? Better is base your communication between PHP and JS on the JSON. So in the PHP return array in json_encode() function and then load json by $.getJSON(). As a result you have clean code and control types of data. Note that values of points, should be numbers, not strings.